# parsing json in swift

Tags: ios, memory-management, swift, linkedin-api

I'm trying to read the Linkedin response in swift.

My object is something like this ["positions":["values":["data1","data2","data3"]]]

```
        if let positions: NSDictionary = info["positions"] as NSDictionary!{
        if let positionsInfo: [NSDictionary] = positions["values"] as? [NSDictionary]{
            for position : NSDictionary! in positionsInfo {
                dosomething(position, person:usr)
            }
        }
    }
```

If I do a StepOver line by line it works correctly. But if I run it i'll get a EXC_BAD_ADDRESS(code=1,address=0x7966b04) I enabled Zombie objects and ran it on Instruments. I'm pretty sure this is the code which is causing the problem. But not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: There is no [JSON](http://json.org), there are dictionaries and arrays. [JSON](http://json.org) is a lightweight data-interchange format.

Comment: The types are wrong. The object is a dictionary of a dictionary of an array of strings. Really study-up on JSON, it is rather simple. There is also no reason to use `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, just use `Dictionary` or `Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you used `!` you opened yourself up for crashes if there were any problem. You must use `as?` to make sure that the data is actually what you think it is.

There are many blog posts out there on how to safely parse JSON into Swift data structures. It's now almost a rite of passage for Swift bloggers.

- http://robots.thoughtbot.com/efficient-json-in-swift-with-functional-concepts-and-generics
- http://chris.eidhof.nl/posts/json-parsing-in-swift.html
- https://github.com/owensd/json-swift
- https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON
- Of course the many packages: https://github.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+json
- http://robnapier.net/functional-wish-fulfillment - My own version on top of all the others

Comment: One fear about Swift usage I have is exactly that, `!` becomming an "Asprin" for every problem.

Comment: In the really old days of relay logic we used to call diods "Asprin", they were use to prevent sneak back paths. But yeah, meth.